# Prove that $\chi(\mathbb{R}^d)\le (4d)^{d/2}$

Tags: geometry, coloring

For $d\ge1$ an integer let $\chi(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the chromatic number of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (the least number of colors with which $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be colored such that no two points with distance $1$ have the same color). I am asked to prove that $\chi(\mathbb{R}^d)\le (4d)^{d/2}$ holds for all $d\ge1$.

An idea would be to give a periodic colouring of $\mathbb{R}^d$ like the $7$-coloring of $\mathbb{R}^2$ described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem. Perhaps it is possible to divide $\mathbb{R}^d$ in hypercubes with diameter 1. However, I have no clue how to color these hypercubes.

Can anyone help me to establish this upper bound for $\chi(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Comment: A simple approach is outlined here: www.cs.bme.hu/~geza/chromatic.pdf The main idea is to tile $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $d$-dimensional permutohedra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron).

Comment: I am afraid that it is not so easy to generalize this method for $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R^d}$.

Comment: Why? [Have a look at this link](https://books.google.it/books?id=k2an6eBxn3kC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=permutohedron+tiling&source=bl&ots=Y3C4YwW9DY&sig=P0T25tYm9bV9mPu4ny3zh1rUo0M&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw-uPIjL_PAhXpLMAKHSGjAFwQ6AEISzAF#v=onepage&q=permutohedron%20tiling&f=false)

Comment: What will my algorithm of coloring the permutohedra be and how many colors will I use? I guess that a point in $\mathcal{T}_{i_1,\ldots,i_d}$ should get color $i_1+3i_2+\ldots+ (2d-1)i_d \mod ?$. Also, in the article the proof that the algorithm works, is done by listing all 'dangerous triples', but how should I do this for general d? I actually hoped for a more elementary solution for this problem.